# Populate HTML Select using spycopg2 Python Flask

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

Im new using flask and 
I want to pull that data and display it as selection option in html form using FLASK.
This is my select

```
<span class="input-group-addon">Unity</span>
    <select name="unity" class="selectpicker form-control">

    </select>
```

and i want to populate it with this data

```
@app.route("/stadistics/unity")
def unity():
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select unity from mse.unity")
    unity = cursor.fetchall()
    print (unity)
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Python code:

```py
@app.route("/stadistics/unity")
def unity():
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select unity from mse.unity")
    unity = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('my_html_file.html', unity=unity)
```

HTML, with Jinja2 for loop:

```html
<select name="unity" class="selectpicker form-control">
    {% for u in unity %}
    <option value="{{ u }}">{{ u }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Flask includes Jinja2 template engine by default, you can pass the variables of your choice to your HTML template, when you call `render_template()`, take a look at docs for more detailed information: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates